# How to implement an AfterStep getting the Tag and passing the scenario as an argument?

Tags: ruby, testing, cucumber, automated-tests, bdd

I'm searching a way to implement an AfterStep(@tag) passing the scenario as an argument. Unfortunately, this isn't working and I couldn't find a way to do it.

I also looked into the [Cucumber Hooks documentation](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks), but that didn't help as well.

The way I'm trying to implement:

```
  AfterStep('@screenshot') do |scenario|
    # Add screenshot to baseline folder.
    @helper = Helper.new
    @helper.take_screenshot(scenario.name, 'screenshots/baseline')
  end
```

When I run the tests, I get this error:

```
undefined method `name' for #<Cucumber::Core::Test::Result::Passed:0x007f2b818e6d50> (NoMethodError)
```

The objective here is to take a screenshot from the scenarios with the @screenshot tag.

Comment: in case of java, there is a way for it in QAF-Gherkin [ https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf-gherkin-client.html ] by means of step listener. You can check if the same thing you can implement for ruby

Comment: Why use AfterStep and not After (scenario) ? Try: After('@screenshot') do |scenario| .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sam pointed out, using `After('@screenshot') do |scenario|` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
After('@screenshot') do |scenario|

  output_folder = (ENV["output_folder"] || "features/output") + "/" + ENV['TIMESTAMP'][0,10]
  scenario_folder = output_folder + '/' + 'failure screenshots' + '/'

  if scenario.respond_to? (:title)
    script_name = scenario.name
  else
    script_name = scenario.scenario_outline.title
  end

  screenshot_file = scenario_folder + script_name.gsub(/[\/\\| <>\n\r]+/, "_")[0..90] + ".png"
  current_path = ''


  begin
    screenshot_file.split(/\//).map{|m| m.split(/\\/)}.flatten.each {|folder|
    next if folder =~ /\.png/
    current_path += folder + "/"
    next if folder.downcase =~ /:/
    Dir.mkdir(current_path) unless File.exists?(current_path)
    }

  @browser.screenshot.save screenshot_file
  embed screenshot_file, 'image/png'

  rescue Exception => e
    p e.message
    p "Could not capture screenshot"
  end

end
```

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I was looking for. I do have a helper method to take screenshots. My doubt was how to use the After (or AfterStep) method passing the scenario as argument. But thanks.